# Converting date in excel

Tags: excel, date

I need to convert the below date format in excel.

Currently I have: `Fri Jan 06 05:10:31 2017`

Current Format : `ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy`

I wanted to be in the following format: `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

Comment: I have tried the usual format cells and converting into date but this is not working even in the sample it will not show how I need it to be

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the day from the string, convert it to a number then format the way you want.

To do the first two steps use this formula:

```
=--MID(A1,5,LEN(A1))
```

[image]

The third is a custom format:

[image]

---

As per the comment:

[image]

Comment: It converted the way told me however with a slight problem.

For example: Sun Jan 01 03:50:17 2017 when doing the above mentioned it converted to: 01/01/2001 03:50 do you know why is this pleasE?

Comment: I get `01/01/2017 03:50:17` with those numbers,  check your actual data and ensure that what you typed is exactly what is in the cell.  You may have a typo or a non-printable character in the date you are trying to change.  @AnnaliseAzzopardi

Comment: @AnnaliseAzzopardi see edit for proof.  I copied and pasted what you typed in your comment and it worked without issue.

Comment: I still did not manage to get it like you...when I tried doing it =MID(A8,5,LEN(A8)) it worked but it still being shown as string...do you have any further suggestions please?

Comment: You are missing the `--` to change it to a number.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,9,2)&MID(A1,5,3)&RIGHT(A1,4))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running into trouble with regional DMY vs. MDY system settings, parse it out longhand so no interpretation is performed; i.e. give the conversion no options.

```
=DATEVALUE(REPLACE(MID(A2, 4, LEN(A2)), 8, 9, ","))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A2, 12, 8))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can format it and everything from the formula bar (no need to go in and set formatting).

```
=TEXT(MID(A1,5,LEN(A1)),"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

[image]

Comment: Except that Text returns just that a Text String that looks like a date and not a true date.  So sorting requires and extra step, as it will require Excel to convert the text string to a number to sort, where as putting it as a format keeps the number and all math and sorting becomes quicker and with less flaws due to the underlying value being a number and not text.

Comment: The asker's question did not reflect any additional processing so I provided what I thought was a slightly more elegant solution; however, you make a very fair point, and I admit I should have made that clarification myself.    :)

Comment: @billyhoes - I have tried doing it your way as well...what is happening is that the data when converted it is taking the date for Jan 06 as 01/01/06 not 06/01/2017 do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I am not getting the same result using the information you provided so I'm not sure how to correct it on your end.  That said, if you want to brute force MAKE it display what you want (without regard to later sorting or running calculations based on it you can use this formula (it's ugly but it works - assumes date value is in A1): 
=MID(A1,9,2) & "/" & TEXT((MONTH(DATEVALUE(MID(A1,5,3)&"1"))),"00") & "/" & RIGHT(A1,4) & " " & MID(A1,12,8)