# Date type data gets changed from “dd/mm” to “mm/dd” type while importing tab delimited text file to excel Through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, datetime

While going through SO featured post [**VBA, Date formatting issue**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52655007/vba-date-formatting-issue)  I think the problem could not be simply brushed aside by saying format issue. In my workplace we are living with similar type of problem for around last 12/13 years.  However we worked around with some crude workaround approach.  But the fundamental problem is still very much intact.

Since the real data we are processing are technical in nature and could not be divulged and contains more than 6000 rows and 50 columns. Also actual data processing in consequence of importing the data consists of pages VBA coding. I reproduced the problem with small factitious sample data only.

When a tab delimited text file was imported manually, the dates in a single column (also consists of Numbers Blanks & texts in the same column) gets imported normal in date format (“dd/MM/yyyy”).  Macro was also recorded during the manual operation

But when the same task was performed through VBA.

1. The dates with day value more than 12 appears as text type.
2. The dates with day value less than 13 appears as date type but 01/04/2017 (i.e. 1-Apr-2017) gets changed to 04/0!/2017 (i.e. 4-jan-2017) and so on.

   ```
   Fname = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\SO Sample.TXT"

   Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=Fname, Origin:=xlMSDOS, _
       StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlNone, _
       ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, _
       Space:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar:="*", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
       Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1))
   ```

My first question is **what is the catch between manual operation and VBA Coding**?

1. For satisfaction, coding was replaced and tried with recorded macro
2. VBA macro tested for multiple option with File Origin:=xlMSDOS, Xl Windows , 437 etc.
3. Regional setting of all the machines of that particular department is in same date format “dd/MM/yyyy” only.
4. Since this is an age old process, Macros/VBA Codes are tried in Office 2007 and old versions only.
5. Normally all formats are kept General.

Now the age old workaround we are still working modified for sample data

```
Sub Macro1()
Fname = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\SO Sample.TXT"

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=Fname, Origin:=xlMSDOS, _
        StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlNone, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, _
        Space:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar:="*", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
        Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1))

    SrcName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Range("A1:C40").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Activate
    Sheet1.Range("A5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows(SrcName).Activate
    Range("A1:A1").Select
    Selection.Copy                     ' To release vast clipboard date
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate


 For X = 5 To 40
 Xdate = Cells(X, 2).Text
 Cells(X, 5).Value = Xdate
 Ydate = Cells(X, 5).Value
    If IsDate(Xdate) And IsDate(Ydate) Then
    Zdate = CDate(Ydate)
    'If DateDiff("d", Ydate, #1/1/1900#) > 0 Then Zdate = ""     'to filter out numeric data interpreted as date/time
    Else
    Zdate = ""
    End If
 Cells(X, 6).Value = Zdate
 Next

'Next are the sections of processing the data beased on the non empty date values found in column 6.
End Sub
```

Here when Cells(X, 2).Text was put into Cells(X, 5)

1. The dates with day value more than 12 appears remains text type in column 5.
2. The dates with day value less than 13 appears as date type but 01/04/2017 (i.e. 1-Apr-2017) which got changed to 04/0!/2017 (i.e. 4-jan-2017) in Col 2  Again get changed to 01/04/2017 (i.e. 1-Apr-2017) in Col 5

Now my second question is, **what is happening when we put Cells(X, 2).Text into Cells(X, 5)** ?[image: Sample data]

This is strictly for academic interest, I changed department, people are happy with old work around and no one want to tinker with age old code. But my hunch the solution must be a very simple single line tweak and made us utter “Oh How can we missed this silly thing for years”.

**Edit2:** Further little experiment was done on how Cells.text works with various dates & regional settings (both “DMY” &  “MDY”).  Few sample dates are entered in a excel file and a simple loop executed to put column B cells text to column D.
[image: The result is]
I come to the conclusion that **irrespective of regional setting VBA Cells.Text interpret date as displayed in USA format (mdy)** . When the same is put on another cell (in case, Regional setting is “DMY” and Month and Date is possibly interchangeable i.e. date < 13), it gets interchanged. 
I still welcome any other better understanding in the subject.

Comment: `VBA` assumes US regional settings. If your setting use dd/mm format, add `Local:=True` to the `Opentext` command.

Comment: @Rory Thanks . Checked.- Worked like magic. Now I will go to terrace  and shout "Oh How can we missed this silly thing for years". Can you give me clue about 2nd part of my question?.

Comment: @ Rory Please put it as an answer, so that at least I can accept It, it freed up me from decade old inquest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA assumes US regional settings. If your settings use `dd/mm` format, add `Local:=True` to the `Opentext` command.

Re the second part, you forgot to use `CDate` when putting `XDate` in the cell.

Comment: I intentionally not used Cdate(Xdate) as it only duplicate  04/0!/2017 (i.e. 4-jan-2017) from in Col 2  to column 5. (Even just now I checked it with wrapping it with “if Isdate … Then” as col2 contains other data types and throw variable type error). But **somehow Cells(X,5).value= cells(X,2).Text  do the trick and convert 04/0!/2017 (i.e. 4-jan-2017) in Col 2  to 01/04/2017 (i.e. 1-Apr-2017) in Col 5.** I still could not understand the logic behind it.  It worked during some trial & error and still working for years.

Comment: I edited the post with some more findings in line of your thinking.. may please have a look.